# UITableView - show different image sizes on different devices

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm in process of building magazine style app that lets users consume info about history. For navigation I use tableview with images in cells. My problem is - they looks good only in iPhone 5, like this:

[image]

and on iPhone 6 it looks stretched, not good, like this

[image]

I think I need different cell sizes and different image sizes based on device. I know, how to make cells dynamic height, but i dont know, how to show images for different aspect ratios on different devices. How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: did you use auto layout on the cell

Comment: yes, I use height, width, aspect ration and clip image to both top and bottom and both left and right

Answer (score 0):

You may should calculate the cell height programmatically and use 0px spacing constraints for the image on all sides. If you set the Mode of the UIImage to Scale To Fill and calculate the height well it will work.

You can calculate the size on this way:

```html
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return tableView.bounds.size.width * 0.25 //Or what you need
    }
```

Comment: How to calculate height ? Everything else that you mentioned i already tried, and instead of images I got some stretching mess

Comment: there is some progress, but looks not good https://s.mail.ru/54U1YhGEdxds/img-2015-10-02-19-52-37.png also tried aspect fit - https://s.mail.ru/5BYSVfSQrfQV/img-2015-10-02-19-55-09.png images have much better size, but there is problem with overall cell

Comment: set the content mode of the uiimage to asspectfit or fill.

Comment: https://s.mail.ru/45nNqjC5prNp/img-2015-10-02-20-02-07.png and https://s.mail.ru/2ti1bitfXwmQ/img-2015-10-02-20-03-55.png

Answer (score 0):

Your cells on the iphone 6 don't have the same aspect ratio of the iphone 5. They should be taller. 
Do as @gabriel mention, set the imageview margins to 0 and return a specific height depending on if it is an iPhone 5 o 6.

Comment: how can I calculate height for different devices ?

Comment: something like this `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if(iphone5) return someHeight; else return someOtherHeight;
    }`